# Tcl GET Request Add Query

Tags: http, get, request, tcl

Recently I have been looking into simple Tcl GET requests using the https package with the tls package. What I would like to do, is the equivalent of requesting "https://example.com/?query_param=5" and retrieving the data It sends back. So far I have the standard:

```
package require http
package require tls

http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]
dict set hdrs query_param 5
set req [::http::get url https://example.com/ -headers $hdrs]
set rec [::http::data $req]

#Handle Data etc...
```

I have also tried:

```
set req [::http::get url https://example.com/?query_param=5]
set rec [::http::data $req]
```

But no luck. I have looked about online but found nothing to fix it and these 2 ideas were my best bet. I'm not getting the expected data received from the sites reply. Is the problem my code (which I suspect) or the site itself? Thanks and Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use the [`-command`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/http.htm#M21) option as well. You will need to create a proc, then give the name of that new proc to `command`, and when you get a response, the proc will get executed.

Comment: @Jerry Ok, I will look into it! thanks for the help. are there any examples that can help?

Comment: It's in the link. The manual has an example proc, and you just need to add **-command _commandName_** to the geturl command

Comment: You don't need the `-command` option. That is only needed if you want non-blocking operation.

Comment: Your code indicates you use `::http::get url`. Note that the actual command is `::http::geturl`, without a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to build GET parameters is by string concatenation, but the `http::formatQuery` command may help.

```
package require http
package require tls
http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]

dict set params query_param 5
# Quoted just for better highlighting here on Stack Overflow
set urlBase "https://example.com/"
set req [::http::geturl $urlBase?[http::formatQuery {*}$params]]
set rec [::http::data $req]
```

If you want to use a POST instead, use the `-query` option:

```
package require http
package require tls
http::register https 443 [list ::tls::socket -tls1 1]

dict set params query_param 5
set urlBase "https://example.com/"
set req [::http::geturl $urlBase -query [http::formatQuery {*}$params]]
set rec [::http::data $req]
```

If you're not getting the results you expect, something else is going wrong. There are a vast number of ways that HTTP(S) requests can fail, so there's no way to give a generic helpful answer there.